# Error when returning [anArray count] in numberOfRowsInComponent in UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have a UIViewController that has a UIPickerView and UITableView.
The UIPicker has 3 components.

When I try to define the number of components in each array by returning [anArray count], the program freezes without throwing an error when loading the UIViewController.

When I put NSLogs in `viewDidLoad:` for `[self.hours count]`, `[self.minutes count]`, and `[self.meridiem count]`, the correct number of values are returned.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *tempHours = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 12; i++) [tempHours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(i+1)]];
self.hours = [NSArray array];
hours = tempHours;
[tempHours release];

NSMutableArray *tempMinutes = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= 59; i++) [tempMinutes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
self.minutes = [NSArray array];
minutes = tempMinutes;
[tempMinutes release];

NSMutableArray *tempMeridiem = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= 1; i++) [tempMeridiem addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
self.meridiem = [NSArray array];
meridiem = tempMeridiem;
[tempMeridiem release];

}
```

Now, in `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:Component:`, the code freezes without an error if I try to output `[anArray count]`(where anArray is a placeholder for hours, minutes, and meridiem). If I set numberOfRows to an integer value, or to `component+1` everything works just fine.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSInteger numberOfRows;

if (component == 0) {
    // numberOfRows = component+1;
    numberOfRows = [self.hours count];
}
else if(component == 1) { 
    // numberOfRows = component+1;
    numberOfRows = [self.minutes count];
}
else { 
    // numberOfRows = component+1;
    numberOfRows = [self.meridiem count];
}

return numberOfRows;

}
```

I have a feeling my NSArrays (hours, minutes, meridiem) aren't being retained, but running the Analyzer doesn't show me that I have any memory leaks in that ViewController.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating unnecessary arrays and not retaining the ones that count. See your code:

```
self.hours = [NSArray array]; 
hours = tempHours; 
[tempHours release];
```

Here you created an autoreleased array and set it to your self.hours property (which hopefully has a `retain` keyword attached to it). But then the very next line you access the ivar directly and set it to `tempHours`. Then you send a release message to `tempHours` without having ever retained it. Since tempHours is autoreleased it will magically disappear on the next drain of the auto release pool. I believe what you wanted to do is:

```
self.hours = tempHours;
```

Ditto for your other array collections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I actually had `self.hours` before. Not sure why I removed it. Regardless, this doesn't fix the problem. The code still crashes when I try to invoke the ViewController modally or directly (via the TabBarController).

Comment: @ArtSabintsev - what error message are you getting? Did you implement all the necessary delegate methods?

Comment: No error messages - that's what's bothering me. The delegate and dataSource are there, and hooked up to the File's Owner. The thing is, the program works when I return an integer value directly (e.g., 5) for the number of rows for each component.

Comment: @ArtSabintsev - If its crashing without error then you may have a runaway loop. Did you try putting a log message in your `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent` like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked fine without the call to [anArray count]. Anyway, I found the problem. Answering my question in just a sec.

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation yet to answer my question, I'll just write it here for now: 

The problem was not in the ViewController I was trying to display. I just copied the interface and implementation files into a new project, and once I compiled it, everything worked like a dream. 

The problem is with the RootViewController of my project that modally invokes this controller. Apparently, I have a memory leak in that controller that should be trivial to fix. Thank you for theattempts, and for reminding me to add that `self.` that I accidentally took out.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
self.hours = [NSArray array];
hours = tempHours;
```

you should just use

```
self.hours = tempHours;
```

What was happening in your original code was:

1. `self.hours` is set to an array created by `[NSArray array]`. Call it `a`. `a` is correctly retained.
2. now, `hours` is set to `tempHours`. This directly accesses the ivar, without using the setter. So, it doesn't retain `tempHours`. `a` is lost without being correctly released, too.
3. `tempHours` is released. It's not retained by anybody, so it's dealloc'ed, too.

So, don't do that. You'd like to read [the memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).  I can't believe the Analyzer (below the Build command) didn't catch this mistake... maybe you'd like to file a bug toward the LLVM team about this case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As I told @Perception below, I actually had self.hours in my code before. Not sure why I removed it. Regardless, putting it back doesn't fix the problem. The code still crashes when I try to invoke the ViewController modally or directly (via the TabBarController).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the ViewController I was trying to display. I just copied the interface and implementation files into a new proejct, and once I compiled it, everything worked like a dream.

The problem is with the RootViewController of my project that modally invokes the controller with the UIPickerView. Apparently, I have a memory leak in there. Should be trivial to fix.

Thanks everyone for your help!